# Showing underlying Link on mouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched a bit and was unable to find an answer that suited my question. Albeit using z-index and absolute positioning would seem to work, it doesn't.

What I am trying to do is have a menu that slides to the left on mouseover, displaying the underlying link... I've been trying to get it to work without much success. I tried using absolute positioning on the cloned element to place it behind its parent, but that didn't work. I used z-index to make sure the clone was behind its parent as well.

My code is as follows:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="#" data-slide-text="slide-aaa">aaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" data-slide-text="slide-bbb">bbb</a></li
</ul>



(function ($) {
$.fn.doIt = function () {      
    this.find('li')
        .css({
            overflow : 'auto'
        })           
        .hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('a:first').animate({
                    marginLeft : "-150px"
                }, 'fast')
        },
            function(){
                $(this).find('a:first').animate({
                    marginLeft : "0px"
                }, 'fast')                    
        }) 
    this.find('a')
        .each(function(){
           var slideText = $(this).data('slideText');
           $(this)
                .clone()
                .text(slideText)
                .appendTo($(this).parent())
                .addClass('slideClass')
        });
};
})(jQuery);
```

The CSS used is:

```
#nav li{
   list-style: none;
   float: left;
   width: 150px;
   height: 20px;
   color: #CCCCCC;
   height: 60px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
}

#nav a{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 150px;
   z-index: 1;
   background: #777777;
}

.slideClass{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   display: block;
   background: #000000;
   color: #6699dd;
   z-index: 3;
}
```

You can see a live example at: 
[jQuery slide menu](http://davidlallone.com/learn/javascript/)

Comment: you forgot to call `$('#nav').doIt();` as in original example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your CSS in a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6er16te/1/)**

The key changes I've made are to your css:

```
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I also removed your `height:` declarations for `#nav li` and `position:` related declarations for `.slideClass`. Finally, I've changed `#nav a` to be `display: inline-block;` as well.

Comment: This is basically the effect I am looking for. It slides to the left as you would expect.

Is there a reason the background doesn't change? (per the slideText class has the black background) 

-- bear with my ugly colors and some debug code I left lingering. 

You can see the live example (modified, and edited with the code you provided) at the link in the original question. 

I just can't get the background to show black

Comment: @Imperialized, yes the colour is set with `#nav` as a parent in the selector. To override you could use `!important` or you could use a different selector: `#nav slideClass` (or you could change your a selector to be less specific).

Comment: Ok, I got it now. I didn't realize that it didn't overwrite the style when you selected them as such. Changing it to ( class="navlink" ) and making navlink the selector gave the effect without having to use !important to override the style. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Imperialized no problem. There is actually a bit of science to selector hierarchy, it's not as simple as last in order of being processed.

Comment: Already tried. Unfortunately I just created my account here today. And I understand that it isn't the last to be processed. I know it goes inline-style up to linked stylesheets. I just assumed the by adding that class directly to the element would cause it to overwrite the general link selector colors. Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this was what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/t4ag1tby/

Changed the li a to absolute

```
#nav a{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    ...
}
```

And the hover action to animate the position instead of margin.

```
            .hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).find('a:first').animate({
                        left : "-150px"
                    }, 'fast')
            },
                function(){
                    $(this).find('a:first').animate({
                        left : "0px"
                    }, 'fast')                    
            })
```

Comment: looks to me as though you're hiding the link when I hover

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I take that back. The effect in JSFiddle is the effect that I am looking for, but it doesn't exactly work as I wanted it to. Basically, when you hover over the link, it is supposed to show the same link (although a different color). Basically looking to create a sliding animation for a menu, but keeping the link intact.